# Wine runs explorer.exe instead of app

Tags: wine, steam

I installed the Windows version of Steam in Wine, and for the most part it works. But I bought Worms Armageddon and installed it, but when I try to run it, I just get the Wine Explorer, like below. I ran it from the launcher, set the path to include the Worms directory, ran it from the terminal - they all ended up giving me this.[image: Wine Explorer]

Navigating to the Worms directory within explorer.exe and running WA.exe just made another instance of explorer.exe.

The only terminal output is a few fixmes:

`fixme:nstc:NSTC2_fnSetControlStyle2 mask & style (0x00000004) contains unsupported style(s): 0x00000004
fixme:shell:IShellBrowser_fnSendControlMsg stub, 0x141ff8 (2, 1026, a003, 0, 0x33f488)
fixme:shell:IShellBrowser_fnSendControlMsg stub, 0x141ff8 (2, 1026, a004, 1, 0x33f488)
fixme:shell:IShellBrowser_fnSendControlMsg stub, 0x141ff8 (2, 1025, a003, 1, 0x33f488)
fixme:shell:IShellBrowser_fnSendControlMsg stub, 0x141ff8 (2, 1025, a004, 1, 0x33f488)
fixme:shell:IExtractIconW_fnExtract (0x151158) (file=L"C:\\windows\\system32\\shell32.dll" index=-35 (nil) 0x33f188 size=00000014) semi-stub
fixme:shell:IExtractIconW_fnExtract (0x157428) (file=L"C:\\windows\\system32\\shell32.dll" index=-16 (nil) 0x33f188 size=00000014) semi-stub
fixme:shell:IExtractIconW_fnExtract (0x157408) (file=L"C:\\windows\\system32\\shell32.dll" index=-235 (nil) 0x33f188 size=00000014) semi-stub
fixme:shell:IExtractIconW_fnExtract (0x159600) (file=L"@C:\\windows\\system32\\shell32.dll" index=-33 (nil) 0x33f188 size=00000014) semi-stub
fixme:shell:IExtractIconW_fnExtract (0x158e20) (file=L"C:\\windows\\system32\\shell32.dll" index=-9 (nil) 0x33f188 size=00000014) semi-stub`

I'm using wine-1.8 from the Wine PPA on Ubuntu MATE 15.10.

Comment: I tried to install and run on another machine that has Wine 1.6.2 installed, and while there is the issue with Steam and dwrite, Worms works just fine (aside from MATE not liking 640x480 resolution, but I run it in a virtual desktop). BUT this is not a solved problem, because I can't keep 1.6.2 forever.